Android Animator and ObjectAnimator
I am new in android and I'm looking for a way to implement animations in my project. I guess Android Studio does not provide inbuilt antimation view. Let me knoe if you have any idea about animation in Android which I couldn't find anywhere else.
I have tried this:
<set
    android:ordering=["together" | "sequentially"]>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="string"
        android:duration="int"
        android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
        android:valueTo="float | int | color"
        android:startOffset="int"
        android:repeatCount="int"
        android:repeatMode=["restart" | "reverse"]
        android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

    <animator
        android:duration="int"
        android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
        android:valueTo="float | int | color"
        android:startOffset="int"
        android:repeatCount="int"
        android:repeatMode=["restart" | "reverse"]
        android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

    <set>
        ...
    </set>
</set>


What are you trying to achieve? Please edit your post and include that information.

Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/animation/choose-api
